# How to determine remote PC network address?

Tags: networking, ip

Let's say I have two PCs connected with ethernet cable. No NAT, VPN, routers ... nothing, just one cable with two PCs connected to both ends. For example PC1 could have an IP 192.168.1.1/24 (actually I do not know this IP it is just an example). I want to set up appropriate IP for PC2 to be able to communicate with PC1. The problem is that I do not know neither PC1 IP nor the network address of PC1 (the 192.168.1.1/24 was used just as example). In other words I cannot set up PC2 NIC as 192.168.1.77 and start nmap on 192.168.1.1-255 range because I do not know that the PC1 IP lies somewhere in 192.168.1.1-255 range, it can be 192.168.2.1-255 or 127.20.7.1-255 or whatever you can imagine. How can I determine what network does PC1 use? I can set PC2 NIC to promisc mode, but what if PC1 does not send anything? Is there any better option as scanning whole private addresses space (that would be madness)

EDIT: I am asking this question because I am interested in how stuff works and if some hacks (using supernetting or something like that) which are supported by theory behind networking allows this. Answers like go to PC1 and check it's IP manually is not what I'm searching' for.

Comment: I have edited question to be more clear

Comment: I know, but this is not the question. I have no access to PC1.

Comment: Your question does not compute.  If they are directly connected then they are in the same building.  This is an actual problem you have?  In other words this isn't some theoretical problem your trying to solve?

Comment: Lets say that I have router (PC1) which I used a long time ago and had there a pretty nice configuration (which does not send any ARP or another discoveries, just silently listens for incoming connections) which I don't want to lose (I cannot reset it). Now I would like to connect to router and read this configuration but unfortunately I forgot the IP range which I set. Is this OK as example?

Comment: "Why would you have to look at the 127.20.7.1 block when you just said that PC1 is in the 192.168.1.1/24 range." Because I do not know in which range PC1 is. It might be 127.20.7.1 or 192.168.1.1/24 or anything other.

Comment: Which second sentence? Pardon me English but I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: No I do not know It was just an example

Comment: If you don't even know what address block PC1 might be assigned to, what you want, is basically impossible given the amount of possible blocks it could be assigned to.  You will have to go to the PC1 itself to determine what ip address it has been assigned.

Comment: If you don't even know what block PC1 might be assigned to what you want is basically impossible given the amount of possible blocks it could be assigned to.  You will have to go to the PC1 itself to determine what ip address it has been assigned.

Answer (score 2):

If you box is a dsl router it'll give you an IP address using dhcp, it's address is in that packet.

Scanning the entire of 192.168.0.0/16 is not madness, on a normal network it'll take about half an hour. The entire of network ten is a bit much though, it'll take a week.

Population stereotypes will give you some others ... 10.0.0.0/22 for example. Router boxes tend to be put at x.1 x.250-x.254 too.

It's a reasonable idea to setup a tcpdump and powercycle the router. It's likely to send out some packets during startup even if it doesn't otherwise. These *may* be useful.

If your box won't respond to pings nmap can scan using TCP SYN packets.

That's all pretty vague, but then so is your question.

Comment: Router scenario is just an example. I am wondering how to do things in general

Comment: _In general_ you don't do such a thing, the two devices will be programmed to send out broadcast packets to find each-other and then agree the IP addresses, IPX identifiers or whatever else they need to communicate. Usually on startup as I mentioned.

Comment: @user3710044 - This is more or less a valid answer except the user is using zero networking equipment.  He basically would have to scan every address block because he indicate that his examples were just that examples.  I am going to provide an upvote since the answer is valid if the question was answerable.